# Twitter API - How do I Find the date I started following someone

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am developing a application for twitter analytics . I would like to get following information through API.

1. Date, someone followed a user in Twitter.
2. Date, a user is following any other user.

I couldn't find any API that gives this information. Can anybody please help me out on this?

Regards

Comment: I, myself found that as  of now, there is no solution.                 [link]https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3792  [link]https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/443 [link]https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2318

Answer (score 0):

There is no Twitter API method for this.

The only way to do it would be to monitor changes in followers over time and establish your own dates when changes occur. Various services use this technique such as [Qwitter](http://useqwitter.com/).